# OOP - How this relationship could be done in Object-Oriented Programming

Tags: oop, mediator, design-patterns

Suppose there is a class A and it has many instances from class B, and in A, it will have some shared attributes for B to access. Simply I can write this type, I just want to know if there are any pattern or some other good way to make this relationship in OOP.

My idea is straightforward :

```
class A {
      protected int shared;
      public List<B> bList;

      int getShared ()
      {
          return shared;
      }

}

class B {
      protected A _a;

      B (A a) {
            this._a = a;
      }

      void hello () {
            print (this._a.getShared()); 
      }
}
```

As I am pretty much a novice in OOP, so I think maybe there some pattern can do this better, looking forward your ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Each language does this differently. Is there a specific language you would like an example of? You can use OOP/inheritence to accompliyour relationship.

Comment: It seems like you are implementing a "getter function", and yes, that's a very common "pattern" (don't know if one can call it a pattern really).

Comment: Thanks, just want to know if there are better ideas, and it's not for any kind specific programming language, just a thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is looking like [Mediator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern). Except that classically Mediator (A class) has a set of different objects for interacting with or between them without explicit references.

Comment: Thank you, I will figure it out by your advice.